# Splitting and renaming a file

Tags: shell-script

I need to split a file with a particular format and rename it later...

The Split works fine but I'm unable to refer the $file-$each inside my awk command?

Any tips?

```
for file in *.csv
do
  split -n 3 -d -a 2 "$file" "$file--"
  for each in $(seq -w 2 10)
  do
        echo $file--$each

  awk '{filename = $file--$each ".txt"  ; print >> filename}' $file--$each
  done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables do not get expanded inside single-quotes.
The proper way to deal with this is to pass in awk variables on the command line

```
for file in *.csv
do
  split -n 3 -d -a 2 "$file" "$file--"
  for each in $(seq -w 2 10)
  do
        echo $file--$each

  awk -v filestem="$file"--"$each" '{filename = filestem".txt";
  print >> filename}' $file--$each
  done
done
```

Comment: I won't know the variable before hand...

Comment: @user1050619, what variable are you referring to?

Comment: Ignore my comments..Its working...

Comment: I need to get substring of a variable.. awk -v filestem= ${$file--$each:2:5} '{filename = filestem;  print >> filename}' $file--$each   ....and this one does not work

Comment: @user1050619, post that as another question